# if, else if vs. mapping performance

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, mapping

I have a performance question.

I am parsing large text files (bills) and assigning the name of the service provider to a variable based on if certain text appears on the bill.

This is a small sample of what I WAS doing (don't laugh, I know it's messy). All in all, There are approximately 250 if, else if's.

```
if (txtvar.BillText.IndexOf("SWGAS.COM") > -1)
   {
       txtvar.Provider = "Southwest Gas";
   }
else if (txtvar.BillText.IndexOf("georgiapower.com") > -1)
   {
       txtvar.Provider = "Georgia Power";
   }
else if (txtvar.BillText.IndexOf("City of Austin") > -1)
   {
       txtvar.Provider = "City of Austin";
   }
```

// And so on and forth 250 times

Because it grew so big I decided to take a different approach to be cleaner and more efficient. I ended up implementing a mapping, which I store in an external .psv file.

I save that mapping to a variable (this only runs once and takes about 35 milliseconds...

```
var providerMap =
                    System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"U:\Program\ApplicationFiles\ProvidersList.psv")
                    .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
                    .Select(parts => new Provider() { Pattern = parts[0], Name = parts[1] }).ToList();
```

...and then loop through each bill (assigning the provider takes about 2 milliseconds while the if statements took less than half the time....

```
foreach (string bills in files)
                                {
                                    string Provider = providerMap.First(p => txtvar.BillText.IndexOf(p.Pattern) > -1).Name;
                                    OtherStuff();
                                }
```

While this solution is much cleaner, it's surprisingly a lot slower than 250+ if, else if's. I used the stopwatch method to find out that the cleaner method is actually twice as slow as hundreds of if statements. (I tested bills that were towards the beginning and end of the if statements and mapping with similar results)

Can anybody explain this to me? Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How much slower is twice as slow? 4 seconds instead of 2? How much is unacceptable?

Comment: Also, *which part* is slower? Your cleaner method does more than one thing - is the loop through each bill slower, or is it just the reading of your mappings from a file that is slowing things down?  (I assume you're not reading your provider map for *every bill*, right?)

Comment: You have alot of variable, including two entirely separate task.  Which part of the solution is slower?  The `Read` or the `Loop`?  Also, something that may not be being weighed here- Maintainability, 250+ `If`, `Else`, or even `Switch` can become a nightmare if your going to continually build on it.  Those are my thoughts; but without more information I can't help you.

Comment: The initial read of the mapping only happens once and takes about 35 milliseconds. Assigning the provider in the Foreach is the slower part. It takes about 2 milliseconds while the the old if else method takes about .75 milliseconds. I know the difference is minimal and it will not impact my program to much. I just wanted to know if anyone knew why it would take twice as long.

Comment: Loop unrolling is a common optimization technique. You've done the opposite so I'm not surprised it's slower.

Comment: @mike z, Could you expound on loop unrolling a little?

Comment: @ColtonMilne I added an answer discussing loop unrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop unrolling is a technique for improving performance by translating a loop into a sequence of statements. A trivial example

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Could be unrolled to

```
Console.WriteLine(0);
Console.WriteLine(1);
Console.WriteLine(2);
```

There are all sorts of sophisticated techniques for doing this, but the point is that you reduce the number of increments to the loop variable, evaluations of the conditional, and jump instructions in the machine code. Note that this technique is not always a hand-downs performance gain. See [loop unwinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) for more discussion and examples.

You have gone the other way. You've taken a very long `if-else` construct and turned it into

```
string Provider = providerMap.First(p => txtvar.BillText.IndexOf(p.Pattern) > -1).Name;
```

Now all `First` is doing is effectively this (note that `First` will throw in the case that no item matches):

```
Provider found = null;
foreach(var provider in providerMap)
{
    if (txtvar.BillText.IndexOf(provider.Pattern) > -1)
    {
        found = provider;
        break;
    }
}
```

So you can see you've gone the opposite way: from a sequence of statements to a loop.

I think you've gained something you haven't mentioned which is the ability to add providers without recompiling the code, which can be handy.

Comment: Very interesting. I thought that anything would be faster than hundreds of evaluative IF statements.

Comment: @ColtonMilne Think about it this way you are doing the same work as the ifs plus a bunch of work to keep track of your loop state. That said I'm surprised it has much of an effect. If you have large text files, I'd expect the slow part to be reading the files and searching them.

Answer (score 2):

Reading an external file would definitely slow you down. I assume you are reading it just once, but still it would slow you down.

1) Have you tried caching the file's content so that you don't need to read it again? If the mappings don't change much this might be an improvement.

2) Also, why don't you try storing your mapping in a Dictionary object (or similar structure)? You can have it in a separate class file if you like. This is a hardcoded solution, not sure how well it would play within your system.

Comment: The initial read of the mapping only happens once and takes about 35 milliseconds. Assigning the provider in the Foreach is the slower part. It takes about 2 milliseconds while the the old if else method takes about .75 milliseconds. I know the difference is minimal and it will not impact my program to much. I just wanted to know if anyone knew why it would take twice as long.

Comment: Also, I am saving the mapping to a public Generic List variable. It has it's own class with get set operators. Would the Dictionary be quicker than the Generic List?

Comment: Colton, I believe the Linq functions also do loops behind the scenes. Taking that into account, what if the mappings were in a hashtable... My assumption is that the lookup would be faster than looping through a generic List<> object.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the third option ,

1- it is more readable

2- less code ,which can be a performance +1 too .

3- more easy to maintenance

4- no string inside the dll , which also reduce the size of dll